# How to convert between string and byte[] without losing integrity

Tags: c#, openid

I know how to convert from a string to byte[] in C#. In this particular case, I'm working with the string representation of an HMAC-SHA256 key. Let's say the string representation of this key I get from an OpenID OP is:

```
"81FNybKWfcM539vVGtJrXRmoVMxNmZHY3OgUro8+pZ8="
```

I convert it to byte[] like this:

```
byte[] myByteArr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("81FNybKWfcM539vVGtJrXRmoVMxNmZHY3OgUro8+pZ8=");
```

The problem I have with that is that it seems to be losing the original data. If I take the byte array from the previous step and convert it back to a string, it's different from the original string.

```
string check = Convert.ToBase64String(myByteArr);
```

check ends up being:

```
"ODFGTnliS1dmY001Mzl2Vkd0SnJYUm1vVk14Tm1aSFkzT2dVcm84K3BaOD0="
```

which is obviously not the same as the original string representation I started with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With crypto keys, always use `Convert.FromBase64String` and `Convert.ToBase64String`. That way you'll be doing it the standard way and will not lose bytes due to encoding problems. Base 64 string may not be space efficient but it is the preferred method for storage and transport of keys in many schemes.

Here is a quick verification:

```
byte[] myByteArr = Convert.FromBase64String("81FNybKWfcM539vVGtJrXRmoVMxNmZHY3OgUro8+pZ8=");
string check = Convert.ToBase64String(myByteArr);
Console.WriteLine(check);
// Writes: 81FNybKWfcM539vVGtJrXRmoVMxNmZHY3OgUro8+pZ8=
```

Answer (score 2):

The first function (`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`) takes a string (of any kind) and returns a `byte[]` that represents that string in a particular encoding -- in your case, `UTF8`.

The second function (`Convert.ToBase64String`) takes a byte array (of any kind) and returns a string in base64 format so that you can store this binary data in any ASCII-compatible field using only printable characters.

These functions are not counterparts. It looks like the string you're getting is a base64-encoded string. If this is the case, use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get the `byte[]` that it represents, not `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`.

Answer (score 1):

The bytes you get when using `byte[] Encoding.GetBytes(string)` and decoding a base64 string are not the same things.  The former gives you the bytes that represent the string.  You however want to *decode* a base64 string back to the bytes it represents.  In that case you want to use `Convert.FromBase64String()`.

```
string encoded = "81FNybKWfcM539vVGtJrXRmoVMxNmZHY3OgUro8+pZ8=";
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded); // this gives the bytes that the encoded string represents
```

Answer (score 1):

The encoding classes have a [GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) method, to convert it from a byte array back to a string.

If you used the UTF8 encoding to create the byte array, you should use the same coding to get it back again.

```
        var original = "81FNybKWfcM539vVGtJrXRmoVMxNmZHY3OgUro8+pZ8=";
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(original);
        var copy = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
        bool match = (copy == original); // This returns true
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to get the string as bytes but rather the bytes the string represents.